# Meeting Workspace not working with SharePoint Workspace

Tags: meeting-workspace, workspace

## Meeting Workspace / SharePoint workspace problem

### Overview

We are using meeting workspaces with recurring meetings.
The meeting workspace 'Document Library' folders are not however working in SharePoint Workspace.

### Versions

- SharePoint 2010 - 14.0.6029.1000
- SharePoint Workspace – 14.0.6023.1000
- Client OS – Windows XP – SP3

### Document Library Settings

- Series Items == NO

### Accessing the Library in the browser and from Explorer

- Within the browser, the ‘All Meetings’ button works correctly. Shows the current meeting view correctly.
- Shows the ‘All Meetings’ view correctly with different folders for each meeting
- Accessing from Windows Explorer also works correctly

### Problem

When users ‘Sync to SharePoint Workspace’ from the library, the individual folders from the meeting workspace 'Document Library' are not available in the SharePoint Workspace. All the documents in the library are listed but without the individual meeting folders.

I can replicate this error in different environments.

When I change the library settings to the setting Series Items == YES, I get the folders in the SharePoint workspace. I don't however want to do this. I would like to keept the Series Items == NO.